# df command show no output

Tags: linux, centos, df

I'm running the linux distro on my server.When i want to verify the size of the disk, i'm issuing this commnand to get the output.

```
 df -h
```

But it does not produce ANY output.Strangely enough when i'm issuing other command such as fdisk -l or du -h it can show output normally.

Does anyone now why is this happening?Thanks.

edit:

here is the output of cat /etc/fstab

```
 none     /dev/pts       devpts   rw   0     0
```

and this is for mount command

```
 none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw)
 none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc tpe binfmt_misc  (rw)
```

edit(2):

here is the output of cat /proc/mounts

```
 /dev/vzfs / vzfs rw,relatime,usrquota,grpquota 0 0
 proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
 sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
 none /dev/tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
 none /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime 0 0
 none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_msc rw,relatime 0 0
```

Comment: Which distro? How about `df` without `-h`? Are you running as root or `sudo` permission?

Comment: @quanta my distro is centos.I'm running as root.All the command df is not working..

Comment: Please post your /etc/fstab file and also the output of the mount command.

Comment: `df` reads _/etc/mtab_, could you show us this file? Both `fdisk` and `du` do something completely different.

Comment: i've already update my post above.both the output of fstab and mount

Comment: just after running df, run the command "echo $?" to see the exit code of the command. also verify that the file not tempered. its permissions as well.

Comment: fstab and mount show why df shows nothing. Are you in a chrooted environment?

Comment: @ramruma can you explain what do you mean by chrooted environment?

Comment: @Frank the exit code is 0.i've check the file already.It is not tampered and the permission is ok

Comment: Check if the file `/proc/mounts` contains more entries than `/etc/mtab`. If so, you might want to copy it to `/etc/mtab` or better reboot your system to bring it back to a normal state.

Comment: @scai i've already rebooted the system.But it still give me the same problem

Comment: @user119720 Could you tell us about `/proc/mounts` anyway?

Comment: @scai sure..i've already edited my post above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
$ \df
```

`\` to ignore `df` alias.

---

**UPDATE**

> here is the output of cat /proc/mounts
>
> ```
>  /dev/vzfs / vzfs rw,relatime,usrquota,grpquota 0 0
> ```

`/dev/vzfs` --> looks like you're running OpenVZ (check by using [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/)). And if so, root filesystem is mounted by the host system, not the guest, therefore, there is no `/` in the `/etc/mtab` and `df` shows nothing. To fix, link `/etc/mtab` to `/proc/mounts`:

```
rm -f /etc/mtab
ln -s /proc/mounts /etc/mtab
```

Source: http://wiki.openvz.org/Gentoo_template_creation#Make_.2Fetc.2Fmtab_a_symlink_to_.2Fproc.2Fmounts

Comment: nope..its not working.sorry

Comment: @user119720: updated my answer.

Comment: thanks..altough i'm not tested this yet,but you've already point me to the right direction.i will check out this first thing in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are not running the correct df; perhaps there is a badly-named alias or shellscript in your path. Run `which df` to check.

If you are running the correct df, then perhaps it has been corrupted or overwritten. Run `rpm -qf $(which df)` to see which package owns df, and then run `rpm -V packagename` or `rpm -V $(rpm -qf $(which df))` to see if it has changed since installation.

Comment: i've already run which df and it shows me this path :
/bin/df

when i'm running rpm -qf $(which df) it show me this output:
coreutils-5.97-34.el5_8.1

and lastly when i'm running rpm -V $(rpm -qf $(which df)) ,it doesn't show me any output and neither the df command is working

Comment: If you run strace df, is there anything obviously wrong?